# Scrolling Android StickyHeaderGrid

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using `RecyclerView` with `StickyHeaderGridAdapter`.
I'm trying to scroll to specific position, but when I call 
`myrecyclerview.scrollTo(myposition)`
it doesn't work properly and it will scroll to some previous items.
I searched allot but I didn't find any solution unfortunately.

This is my adapter:

```
public class PartsAdapter extends StickyHeaderGridAdapter {

public List<SessionHeaderJavaModel> headers;
private LinkedHashMap<SessionHeaderJavaModel , List<PartJavaModel>> mainList;

public PartsAdapter() {
    this.mainList = new LinkedHashMap<>();
}

@Override
public HeaderViewHolder onCreateHeaderViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int headerType)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    PartHeaderItemBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.part_header_item, parent, false);
    return new MyHeaderViewHolder(binding);
}

@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateItemViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int itemType)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    PartItemBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.part_item, parent, false);
    return new MyItemViewHolder(binding);
}

@Override
public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(HeaderViewHolder viewHolder, int section)
{
   ((MyHeaderViewHolder)viewHolder).setHeaderModel(this.headers.get(section));
}

@Override
public void onBindItemViewHolder(ItemViewHolder viewHolder, int section, int offset) {
    mainList.get(this.headers.get(section)).get(offset).setSection(offset);
    ((MyItemViewHolder)viewHolder).setItemModel(mainList.get(this.headers.get(section)).get(offset));
}

@Override
public int getSectionCount() {
    if(mainList!=null)
    return mainList.size();
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getSectionItemCount(int section) {
    if(mainList!=null && headers!=null && mainList.get(this.headers.get(section))!=null)
    return mainList.get(this.headers.get(section)).size();
    return 0;
}
```

and I initialize my `recylcerview` like this:

```
PartsAdapter adapter=new adapter();
 StickyHeaderGridLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new StickyHeaderGridLayoutManager(1);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I think we need a little bit more context here. Can you please add your RecyclerViewAdapter class and your Main where you initialize the recylcer view. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I add my RecyclerViewAdapter class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is:

```
 recyclerView.scrollToPosition(newPosition + items.get(newPosition).getSessionNo());
```

we should consider the headerItem .